# Linking of database tables by pID

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have problem linking 2 datatables using a pID. It isn't an automated number. The thing is, I have to save the pID number into the database when I select an option in a drop down list. But the options shown are course names (Text).

After selecting from the drop down list, input text into a textbox and then click on a button to save both the pID number and description into the database. In 1 database table, it has the course name and pID number. The 2nd database table has the pID number and description(Save info into here).

I'm only able the save the selectedindex, which isn't the pID number.

.aspx.vb Code

```
    Dim OdbcCon As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
    Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand

    OdbcCon.Open()


    cmd.Connection = OdbcCon
    cmd.CommandText = " insert into StdBookInfo(pID,Description) values ('" & DropDownListStudent.SelectedIndex & "','" & TextBox1.Text & "') "

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Code for drop down list:

```
    sqlcmd3 = "select Course_code + ' - ' + package from StudentPackage order by pID asc "
    sqlcmd4 = "select pID from StudentPackage order by Course_code,package asc "

    cmd3.Connection = OdbcCon
    cmd3.CommandText = sqlcmd3
    DropDownListStudent.Items.Add("")

    reader3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader
    While reader3.Read
        DropDownListStudent.Items.Add(reader3.Item(0).ToString)
    End While
    DropDownListStudent.SelectedIndex = -1



    reader3.Close()
    cmd3.Dispose()
    cmd4.Connection = OdbcCon
    cmd4.CommandText = sqlcmd4
    reader4 = cmd4.ExecuteReader
    I = 0
    While reader4.Read
        pID(I) = reader4.Item(0)
        I = I + 1

    End While
    reader4.Close()
    cmd4.Dispose()
    OdbcCon.Close()
```

Comment: give me table structure

Comment: You need to set the Text and Value properties of each item of DropDownList, then use SelectedValue instead SelectedIndex. Have you done it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Text and Value properties of each item of DropDownList, then use SelectedValue instead SelectedIndex.

```
<asp:DropDownList id="DropDownListStudent" Runat="Server">
  <asp:ListItem Text="Item 1" Value="1"/>
  <asp:ListItem Text="Item 2" Value="2"/>
  <asp:ListItem Text="Item 3" Value="3"/>
  <asp:ListItem Text="Item 4" Value="4"/>
  <asp:ListItem Text="Item 5" Value="5"/>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: I see... is the value="1" the pID numbers?

Comment: But is there a simpler way? cause there's a lot of pID numbers :/

Comment: How are you populating the dropdownlist?

Comment: The data in the drop down list is fixed.

Comment: I've added the code for my drop down list in the qn...
I hope that answers your qn? ):

Comment: Use `DropDownListStudent.Items.Add(reader3.Item(0).ToString, pID)` instead

Comment: the error they give is : Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Add' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: I'll get back to you~ Thanks for your help though!